# what releases are included in a sync?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, image-proc, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are ~monthly 'sync's for each ROS version (e.g. [2019-08-26 kinetic sync](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-kinetic-kame-2019-08-26/10450). I'm assuming that this sync means that these packages are pushed to the `apt` servers. Who or what determines what package releases are in this sync?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm using a package `image_rotate` from `image_proc` on kinetic and I found out that the latest release on apt-get (1.12.23) has a bug in it that got fixed in a later version (1.13.0). However that release did not get included in the latest sync linked above, even though it was introduced a while ago. Is there a way to 'endorse' a package to be included in the next sync?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331672/what-releases-are-included-in-a-sync?/) by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2019-08-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-28**:
Checking [status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=image_rotate](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=image_rotate) and [status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=image_rotate](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=image_rotate) I would observe that in this particular case `1.13` is the Melodic release branch, while `1.12` is the Kinetic one.

@achille: unless the maintainer(s) decide(s) to backport the fix from Melodic to Kinetic, `1.13` is never going to be released into Kinetic.

Note: it could well be that the `1.12` branch already includes the fix you're looking for, but I just wanted to clarify that waiting for `1.13` to appear in a sync / on Kinetic is not what you should do.

If you can clarify which specific fix it is you're missing, perhaps we can see whether it has been backported/applied to Kinetic as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a tool called "bloom" we used to release packages to the ROS build farm to build in a separate testing release of the packages (think of it as bleeding edge). These packages are also available to apt install but with a different ROS packages URL than what you would set up in a production install. The syncs are batch moving all the packages from testing to production releases so the default install packages URL has those packages to be updated.

So what defines what packages are in a sync? It's up to the maintainers to say "I think there's enough changes / updates, lets release a new version" and run the bloom tool to start the build farm process to create the debians on shadow-fixed, and then later synced once a month(ish) to the production set.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0